# When i use MAVEN to build WAR file, why some geronimo-xxx.jar was included into war file?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, geronimo

Below are geronimo jar files were included into my war file when build maven

However, I never include them in `pom.xml`

```
  geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar
  geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar
  geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.2.jar
  geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
  geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.jar
  geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar
  geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec-1.1.2.jar
```

Comment: Can you add your pom.xml? It is most likely pulled in by other dependencies.

Comment: here is my pom.xml https://dl.dropbox.com/u/49101500/pom.xml

Answer (score 2):

Well, some of the plugin / dependency that you are using in your `pom.xml` has cross dependency on `geronimo`, that's why while building, maven is downloading and packaging this dependency war files.

You can use the below command to get the whole dependency tree and check.

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
```

Comment: thank for your help, but i found out which jars depend on geronimo so how to ignore them?

Comment: You can use the `<optional>true</optional>` tag while declaring those dependency. See this [link](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

Answer (score 1):

Some dependency in your pom is bringing in these dependencies with the wrong scope. Just add them to dependency management and change the scope to provided.

Comment: Thank for your answer, so you mean adding geronimo-xx.jar into pom.xml with scope provided, right?

Comment: Use an exclusion of them on whatever artifact pull them in the first place or add them to dependencyManagement with scope provided..